# Angular JS Multiple controller not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hello all i am doing a simple login and registration app. I am using two controllers one for login and one for sign up on same html page.The login is working not the registration.Where am i doing wrong.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html  ng-app="MyApp">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>WeBeR</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-       reset/2.0/reset.min.css">
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?  family=Roboto:400,100,300,500,700,900|RobotoDraft:400,100,300,500,700,900'>
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-  awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/animate.css">
</head>
 <body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="top">
        <h1 id="title" class="hidden"><span id="logo"><span><br><br><br><br>  </span></span></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="login-box animated fadeInUp">
        <div class="module form-module">
            <div class="toggle">
                <h3> SignUp</h3>
                    <i class="fa fa-times fa-pencil"></i>
                <div class="tooltip">
                    Register 
                </div>
            </div>
        <div class="form" ng-controller="SignUpController as ctrl">
            <h2>LogOn</h2>
                <form name="ctrl.signupForm" ng-submit="ctrl.signup()">
<!-- *************************************USERNAME**********************************************************************   -->
                    <div class="error" role="alert" ng-show="errorMsg"><strong>{{errorMsg}}</strong></div><br>
                        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-  error':ctrl.hasErrorClass('userName')}">
                            <input type="text" id="userName" name="userName"   required placeholder="UserName"
                                 ng-model="ctrl.newCustomer.userName" ng- model-options="{ updateOn : 'default blur' }"
                                 ng-focus="ctrl.toggleUsernamePrompt(true)"   ng-blur="ctrl.toggleUsernamePrompt(false)"/>
                        </div>
  ********************PASSWORD**********************************************************************                        
                    <div ng-class="{'has- error':ctrl.hasErrorClass('password')}">
                            <input type="password" id="password" required placeholder="Password"
                            type="{{ctrl.getPasswordType()}}"
                            ng-model-options="{ updateOn : 'default blur' }"
                            ng-model="ctrl.newCustomer.password"/>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit">Sign In</button>
                </form>
        </div>
<!-- *************************************************REGISTRATION******************************************************** -->      
    <div class="form" ng-controller="RegistrationController as rctrl">
        <h2>Create an account</h2>
        <form name="rctrl.regForm" ng-submit="rctrl.register()">
<!-- *************************************************FIRSTNAME******************************************************** -->                 
                    <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error':rctrl.hasErrorClass('firstName')}">
                        <input id="firstName" name="firstName" class="form-control" type="text" required placeholder="First Name"
                            ng-model="rctrl.newCustomer1.firstName" ng-model-options="{ updateOn : 'default blur' }"
                            ng-focus="rctrl.toggleFirstNamePrompt(true)" ng-blur="rctrl.toggleFirstNamePrompt(false)" />
                    </div>
<!-- *************************************************LASTNAME******************************************************** -->                  
                    <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error':rctrl.hasErrorClass('lastName')}">
                        <input id="lastName" name="lastName" class="form-control" type="text" required placeholder="Last Name"
                            ng-model="rctrl.newCustomer1.lastName" ng-model-options="{ updateOn : 'default blur' }"
                            ng-focus="rctrl.toggleLastNamePrompt(true)" ng-blur="rctrl.toggleLastNamePrompt(false)"/>
                    </div>
<!-- *************************************************EMAIL******************************************************** -->                                         
                    <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error':rctrl.hasErrorClass('email')}">
                        <input id="email" name="email" class="form-control" type="email" required placeholder="E-mail"
                            ng-model="rctrl.newCustomer1.email" ng-model-options="{ updateOn : 'default blur' }"
                            ng-focus="rctrl.toggleEmailPrompt(true)" ng-blur="rctrl.toggleEmailPrompt(false)" email-available/>
                                <div class="message-animation" ng-if="rctrl.regForm.$pending.emailExists">checking....</div>
                                <div class="message-animation" ng-if="rctrl.regForm.$error.emailExists">Email exists.</div>
                    </div>
<!-- *************************************************USERNAME******************************************************** -->                                          
                    <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error':rctrl.hasErrorClass('userName')}">
                        <input id="userName" name="userName" class="form-control" type="text" required placeholder="UserName"
                            ng-model="rctrl.newCustomer1.userName" ng-model-options="{ updateOn : 'default blur' }"
                            ng-focus="rctrl.toggleUsernamePrompt(true)" ng-blur="rctrl.toggleUsernamePrompt(false)" user-available/>
                                <div class="message-animation" ng-if="rctrl.regForm.$pending.userExists">checking....</div>
                                <div class="message-animation" ng-if="rctrl.regForm.$error.userExists">UserName exists already.</div>
                    </div>
<!-- *************************************************PASSWORD******************************************************** -->                                                                  
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group" ng-class="{'has-error':rctrl.hasErrorClass('password')}">
                            <input id="password" name="password" class="form-control" required placeholder="Password"
                                type="{{rctrl.getPasswordType()}}"
                                ng-model-options="{ updateOn : 'default blur' }"
                                ng-model="rctrl.newCustomer1.password"
                                />
                         </div>
                    </div>
            <button>Register</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="cta">
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script     src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js">    </script>
<script src="resources/js/register.js"></script>
<script src="resources/js/animate.js"></script>
<script src="resources/js/login.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My JS

```
angular.module('MyApp', [])
.controller('SignUpController',function($scope, $http) {

        var ctrl = this, newCustomer = {
                userName : '',
                password : ''
        };

        var signup = function() {
            if (ctrl.signupForm.$valid) {
                ctrl.showSubmittedPrompt = true;
                submitForm();
                clearForm();
            }
        };

        var register = function() {
            if (ctrl.signupForm.$valid) {
                ctrl.showSubmittedPrompt = true;
                alert("success");
            }
        };


        var clearForm = function() {
            ctrl.newCustomer = {
                    userName : '',
                    password : ''
            };
            ctrl.signupForm.$setUntouched();
            ctrl.signupForm.$setPristine();
        };


        var submitForm = function(userName, password) {

            $http({
                method : 'POST',
                url : 'http://localhost:8081/Classmate/user/getvalid',
                data : {

                    'userName' : $scope.ctrl.newCustomer.userName,
                    'password' : $scope.ctrl.newCustomer.password

                },
                headers : {
                    'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
                }
            }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log(data);
                if (data == false) {
                    var path = "/Classmate/view.jsp";
                    window.location.href = path;
                } else {
                    $scope.errorMsg = "Invalid Credentials";
                }
            }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.errorMsg = 'Unable to submit.Please try after sometime.';
            })
        };

        var getPasswordType = function() {
            return ctrl.signupForm.showPassword ? 'text' : 'password';
        };

        var toggleUsernamePrompt = function(value) {
            ctrl.showUsernamePrompt = value;
        };

        var hasErrorClass = function(field) {
            return ctrl.signupForm[field].$touched
                    && ctrl.signupForm[field].$invalid;
        };

        var showMessages = function(field) {
            return ctrl.signupForm[field].$touched
                    || ctrl.signupForm.$submitted
        };

        ctrl.showUsernamePrompt = false;
        ctrl.showSubmittedPrompt = false;
        ctrl.toggleUsernamePrompt = toggleUsernamePrompt;
        ctrl.getPasswordType = getPasswordType;
        ctrl.hasErrorClass = hasErrorClass;
        ctrl.showMessages = showMessages;
        ctrl.newCustomer = newCustomer;
        ctrl.signup = signup;
        ctrl.clearForm = clearForm;
    })
/*********************************************REG     CONTROLLER*******************************************************/    
        .controller('RegisterController', function($scope, $http) {
        var rctrl = this, newCustomer1 = {
            firstName : '',
            lastName : '',
            email : '',
            zipName : '',
            userName : '',
            password : ''
        };

        var register = function() {
            if (rctrl.regForm.$valid) {
                rctrl.showSubmittedPrompt = true;
                submitRegForm();
                clearForm();
            }
        };

        var clearForm = function() {
            rctrl.newCustomer1 = {
                firstName : '',
                lastName : '',
                email : '',
                userName : '',
                password : ''
            };
            rctrl.regForm.$setUntouched();
            rctrl.regForm.$setPristine();
        };

        var submitRegForm = function() {

            var formData = {
                'firstName' : $scope.rctrl.newCustomer1.firstName,
                'lastName' : $scope.rctrl.newCustomer1.lastName,
                'email' : $scope.rctrl.newCustomer1.email,
                'userName' : $scope.rctrl.newCustomer1.userName,
                'password' : $scope.rctrl.newCustomer1.password
            }
            var response = $http.post(
                    'http://localhost:8081/Classmate/user/save', formData);
            response.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                /*
                 * alert( "Congrats,"+JSON.stringify(data.firstName)+"
                 * Welcome aboard.");
                 */
                var path = "/Classmate/sample.jsp";
                window.location.href = path;
            });
            response.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                alert("Error Details1: " + JSON.stringify({
                    data : data
                }));
            });
        };

        var getPasswordType = function() {
            return rctrl.regForm.showPassword ? 'text' : 'password';
        };

        var toggleEmailPrompt = function(value) {
            rctrl.showEmailPrompt = value;
        };

        var toggleUsernamePrompt = function(value) {
            rctrl.showUsernamePrompt = value;
        };

        var toggleFirstNamePrompt = function(value) {
            rctrl.showFirstNamePrompt = value;
        };

        var toggleLastNamePrompt = function(value) {
            rctrl.showLastNamePrompt = value;
        };

        var hasErrorClass = function(field) {
            return rctrl.regForm[field].$touched
                    && rctrl.regForm[field].$invalid;
        };

        var showMessages = function(field) {
            return rctrl.regForm[field].$touched
                    || rctrl.regForm.$submitted
        };

        rctrl.showLastNamePrompt = false;
        rctrl.showFirstNamePrompt = false;
        rctrl.showEmailPrompt = false;
        rctrl.showUsernamePrompt = false;
        rctrl.showSubmittedPrompt = false;
        rctrl.toggleEmailPrompt = toggleEmailPrompt;
        rctrl.toggleUsernamePrompt = toggleUsernamePrompt;
        rctrl.toggleFirstNamePrompt = toggleFirstNamePrompt;
        rctrl.toggleLastNamePrompt = toggleLastNamePrompt;
        rctrl.getPasswordType = getPasswordType;
        rctrl.hasErrorClass = hasErrorClass;
        rctrl.showMessages = showMessages;
        rctrl.newCustomer1 = newCustomer1;
        rctrl.register = register;
        rctrl.clearForm = clearForm;
    })

.directive(
    'emailAvailable',
    function($timeout, $q, $http) {
        return {
            restrict : 'AE',
            require : 'ngModel',
            link : function(scope, elm, attr, model) {
                model.$asyncValidators.emailExists = function(email) {
                    return $http.get(
                            'http://localhost:8081/Weber/user/getemail?  email='
                                    + email).then(function(res) {
                        +$timeout(function() {
                            model.$setValidity('emailExists', res.data);
                            console.log(res.data);
                        }, 1000);
                    });

                };
            }
        }
    })

.directive(
    'userAvailable',
    function($timeout, $q, $http) {
        return {
            restrict : 'AE',
            require : 'ngModel',
            link : function(scope, elm, attr, model) {
                model.$asyncValidators.userExists = function(userName) {
                    return $http.get(
                            'http://localhost:8081/Weber/user/checkuser?user='
                                    + userName).then(function(res) {
                        +$timeout(function() {
                            model.$setValidity('userExists', res.data);
                            console.log(res.data);
                        }, 1000);
                    });

                };
            }
        }
    });
```

When i try to click on register it doesn't hit the controller

Thank you
Mark

Comment: In your JS, you have the registration controller named `RegisterController`, where as in your HTML, you have `RegistrationController `.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have your controller misnamed. You call it RegisterController in your controller js file but declare it as RegistrationController in your ng-Controller directive.

Comment: That's my bad.Thank you :D